# Java PreparedStatements isClosed performance

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I define a Prepared Statement initially via

```
          prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement("...");
```

and then use it (via a function) in various parts of the code

```
   prepstmt.setDouble(1,x);
   prepstmt.execute();
```

Now I sometimes get "No operations are allowed after statement closed." which is caused by the underlying connection being closed/timed out/reset elsewhere in the code.

Now obviously I could just try/catch the error and reset prepstmt then, but this would make "rerunning" the query more awkward, so was wondering how "costly" it is to do check first with something like

```
   if (prepstmt.isClosed())
          prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement("...");
   prepstmt.setDouble(1,x);
   prepstmt.execute();
```

i.e. checking whether the Prepared Statement is closed before **every** use of it. Guessing this must have some impact on performance, but no idea how significant. Estimating that for my particular application its closed less than 0.1% of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You clearly have a design problem if you're passing `PreparedStatements` around and don't even know if they're closed or not. Sounds like there can be resource leaks also.

However `isClosed()` is not an expensive operation, it simply returns the boolean that is tracking the state of the statement. That is of course driver specific, but I'd be surprised if any driver implemented it in a less effective way.

Comment: Not sure whether its clearly a design problem. For performance I use static connections, i.e. create a connection at the start and use it for numerous hours. However, query performance is (to some extend) random and if this causes a connection to be dropped (e.g. due to a timeout) then all associated statements are also closed. This happens elsewhere in the code and I can catch this and (re)open the connection, but why would I want to recreate all PreparedStatements at the same time? Seems more efficient and much cleaner to do so when and where they are needed.

Comment: I understand what the function returns, but not how it does it. Hence the question on performance.

Comment: Well, the best way would be with a connection pool and creating and closing the statements when they're used, not keeping them around forever and passing around. You also seem to use `execute()` instead of `executeQuery()` and `executeUpdate()`, might want to check those out too, since you (should) know what kind of query you're executing.

Comment: Fair point regarding execute(), thanks. In my application I only use PreparedStatements for frequently repeated statements of which there are only a few, but these are run every few seconds, so dont want the overhead of opening and closing these. Since they are only used in a function and the prepstmts stored in an array within the same class this approach seemed fine.

Comment: PreparedStatements don't really have overhead, especially for something as long as few seconds. It's the connection opening that's the big problem. PreparedStatements can also be cached by the pool (or was it the driver), so you're doing a lot of work that a connection pool can do better than you.

Comment: Dont know much about connection pools which might explain my other comments. But why would I benefit from creating and closing prepared statements if I need them every few secs for hours?

Comment: That's just the standard idiom. It makes more sense in a highly concurrent environment (where you need to use them every few hundred milliseconds for months on end). If you get used to doing it the proper way, you won't need to learn it later on. I'm assuming your application is single threaded, probably not a web-app?

Comment: Yes, the applications is single threaded and not a web app, although I often run multiple (<100) similar instances of it at the same time, but everything is still single threaded.

Comment: Well, then I recommend getting yourself acquainted with connection pooling. It's the "bee's knees" as the youngsters say. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) is my poison of choice, and I don't make uninformed decisions (often).